# rstan and brms cause R and RStudio session abort

Tags: r, stan, rstan, brms

[rstan](/questions/tagged/rstan) and [brms](/questions/tagged/brms) cause [r](/questions/tagged/r) and [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio) session abort. Even re-installation of [rstan](/questions/tagged/rstan) and [brms](/questions/tagged/brms) cause the error.

[image]

[image]

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.0 tools_4.2.0    pacman_0.5.1
```

**Edited**

It is a bug in [rstan](/questions/tagged/rstan) and [brms](/questions/tagged/brms) that cause [r](/questions/tagged/r) `4.2.0` and [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio) session abort. Bug reported here:

[rstan issues](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/issues/1007)

[brms issues](https://github.com/paul-buerkner/brms/issues/1347)

Comment: Not sure if this would work but you could try to set `options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores())`

Comment: Thanks @Basti for your comment. I tried `options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores())` but getting the same error.

Comment: What happens if you try to load the packages in vanilla R (not Rstudio)? Might help isolate whether this is an R error or Rstudio error.

Comment: @SamR: Getting the same error.

Comment: OK... I see you are running R 4.2. Can you load these packages in previous versions of R? Others seem to have had issues loading these packages in 4.2, e.g. [here](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/issues/1007)

Comment: Yes @SamR, I'm using `R 4.2.0` and getting the same error as given [here](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/issues/1007). Any solution please.

Comment: I don't have a solution. I think you'd do better to raise it as a github issue for the package and use an R <= 4.2.0 until the package maintainers release a fix.

Comment: @MYaseen208 Sam was asking if you could downgrade your version of R to try again. You just responded that you are using the most up to date version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @bschneidr for providing solution [here](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/issues/1007#issuecomment-1130040395). Reinstalling `rstan` along with its some dependencies as given below works for me.

```
install.packages(c("BH", "StanHeaders", "Rcpp", "RcppEigen", "RcppParallel", "inline", "loo", "pkgbuild", "rstan"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The above did NOT work for me on a Windows computer.  However, what did work was making sure that I had the proper Rtools version installed on my computer AND that R was able to see it.  I am listing the steps I followed below in case they might help others who cannot run Stan models on their computers. After following these steps, I was able to successfully run Stan models.

It's fair to say that I would have never guessed that Rtools was the root cause of my R Studio sessions aborting whenever I would try to run a Stan model.

**Step 1:** I installed the **pkgbuild** package in R with this command:

```
install.packages("pkgbuild")
```

I then loaded the package in R Studio with this command:

```
library(pkgbuild)
```

**Step 2:** I checked whether R sees the Rtools installation existing on my computer:

```
check_rtools(debug = FALSE)
```

The FALSE message posted by R indicates that Rtools is not visible to R.

**Step 3:** I used the following command to check which version of Rtools was listed in the PATH variable on my computer:

```
Sys.getenv("PATH")
```

This command results in a long string of text. On my computer, I was able to see that this text contained something like **C:\rtools43\usr\bin**. However, the versions of Rtools installed on my computer in the C: drive were earlier versions like Rtools version 4.0 and 4.2. (Rtools version 4.0 was also listed in the PATH, but it was not visible to R.)

**Step 4:** I manually deleted the earlier versions of Rtools from the C:// drive by deleting the corresponding folders.

**Step 5:** I installed on my computer the version with the highest number, Rtools versio 4.3, listed in the PATH variable. That version is available here for Windows computers:

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools43/rtools.html

**Step 6**: I restarted RStudio and typed the commands in the screenshot below to check that R now sees Rtools and to display Rtools installation path:

[image]