# Stan fails to start

Tags: r, rstudio, stan, rstan

I am using R 4.2.0 on Windows 11. When I load the rstan library, the R session is aborted. It says, "R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated." See the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to load in a normal R session outside of RStudio?

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: My answer to all of these questions these days is "try `cmdstanr` instead of `rstan`" ...

Comment: Also present the results from `path.expand("~")` and `Sys.getenv("HOME")`.

Comment: And this: `Sys.which("gcc")`.

Comment: possibly relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72168874/rstan-and-brms-cause-r-and-rstudio-session-abort . Also further things to try at github link at answer link

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled the most recent version of everything: `R (4.2), RStudio (2022.02.2 Build 485)`, `Rtools (4.2)`, `rstan (2.26.x)`. Then, I changed the `R_LIBS_USER` library. I can now run rstan in RStudio. I think changing the `R_LIBS_USER` solved the problem.