# bayes_factor in brms causes R and Rstudio session abort

Tags: r, rstudio, bayesian, brms

bayes_factor in `brms` causes `R` and `Rstudio` session abort. I deleted and reinstalled both `R` and `Rstudio`. At first it wouldn’t fit `brm()` models but after I tried

```
remove.packages(c("StanHeaders", "rstan"))
install.packages("StanHeaders", repos = c("https://mc-stan.org/r-packages/", getOption("repos")))
install.packages("rstan", repos = c("https://mc-stan.org/r-packages/", getOption("repos")))
```

that worked fine. Now I can set priors and fit models for `brm` but when I get to the `bayes_factor()` line both `R` and `Rstudio` crash.
I know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72168874/rstan-and-brms-cause-r-and-rstudio-session-abort) asked a similar question, but it was a bug from nearly a year ago and some of my `brms` does work.

I load

```
library(rstanarm)
library(rstan)
library(brms)
library(BayesFactor)
library(bridgesampling)
```

Any idea what could help?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.3  tools_4.2.3     rstudioapi_0.14
```

[image]

Comment: Does this code abort if you use different GUI?

Comment: I'm not even that familiar with (base) R or RStudio so those are the only ones I tried.

Comment: If it happens outside of Rstudio, you can rule out the IDE as a source of the problem. Could it be a memory size issue? How much data are you using it on?

Comment: not a lot, i dont have data yet so generated a fake set (so that can be easily adjusted if its a problem)

Answer (score -1):

I experienced the same problem

Can you try adding the following to the code inside the brm call

```
brm(..., save_pars=save_pars(all=TRUE))
```

and see if it works?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which [a comment should be used instead of an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173)). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: Thank you! I posted 7 months ago "Nevermind... there was a new syntax for save_pars (save_pars = save_pars(all = TRUE)) and fixing that stopped R from crashing!" but another user deleted it. So thanks a lot, that is exactly what helped!